# Cant change session var with PHP

Tags: php, variables, session

This has been driving me nuts for 4 hours.  I set a session var at login and later I want to change its value like thus:

```
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($_POST)) {
          unset($_SESSION['columns']);
          $_SESSION['columns'] = $_POST['columns'];
    }

    header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Then when I got back to the referrer page the session var 'columns' has the original value set at login, what gives?

The following variation works fine but back on referrer its back to the old value:

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['columns'] = $_POST['columns'];

 //header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 echo "SESSION[columns]=" . $_SESSION['columns'];
 echo "<BR>POST[columns]=" . $_POST['columns'];
```

Comment: Its my first question here please be gentle with me :-) I am sitting here waiting for an answer :-)

Comment: you dont need to use unset

Comment: `unset` will issue a warning if element is not set. And you don't need to unset it as you overwrite it later

Comment: make sure that you have session_srart on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: Are you setting the columns value again inside referer page maybe? Hard to tell without having all the code...

Comment: Yes I have session_start() and yes tried just overwriting it to...same problem...

Comment: no not setting columns value anywhere else...

Comment: @Tom `session_start` does not need to be called for every session param, just one time. And it's called before *if*

Comment: Can it be that you pass params using GET request and not POST or your SESSION is empty? Try setting it without *if* condition or echo something inside it to make sure it's executed

Comment: This will change the value of 'columns' in the current script page but when we go back to the referrer its the old value:

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['columns'] = $_POST['columns'];

header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Comment: Its a form submission using post - checked that!

Comment: And I checked the phpinfo() results to find the session dir and make sure its writable by owner and group...

Comment: SSSSSSOLVED!  Havinga session var called 'columns' and a post var called 'columns' is bad karma, I renamed the session var to 'cols' and all is working now - Bit of a gotcha!  thanks for ya helps